# How to fetch table data based on percentage in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that has data columns like Datetime, prodID, prodNme. Each datetime has 15 minutes difference and repeats 80 to 85 times in the data table. I have to check the count of each DateTime (which can be dynamic) and then get its 15 percent then remove rows from top and bottom of that datetime based on percentage.

For example, I have a datetime '2021-08-09 00:00:00' which count I get is 85 and calculated 15 percent is 12 then I have removed 12 rows from top and 12 rows from bottom from this datetime '2021-08-09 00:00:00'.

Sample data:

| Date/Time | ProdId |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-06-21 00:00:00.000 | 1 |
| 2021-06-21 00:00:00.000 | 2 |
| 2021-06-21 00:00:00.000 | 3 |
| 2021-06-21 00:00:00.000 | 4 |
| 2021-06-21 00:15:00.000 | 1 |
| 2021-06-21 00:15:00.000 | 2 |
| 2021-06-21 00:15:00.000 | 3 |
| 2021-06-21 00:15:00.000 | 4 |
| 2021-06-21 00:15:00.000 | 5 |
| 2021-06-21 00:15:00.000 | 6 |
| 2021-06-21 00:15:00.000 | 7 |

Desired output :

| Date/Time | ProdId |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-06-21 00:00:00.000 | 2 |
| 2021-06-21 00:00:00.000 | 3 |
| 2021-06-21 00:15:00.000 | 4 |
| 2021-06-21 00:15:00.000 | 5 |

Here is what I have tried in loop:

@PER is percentage and @DATETIME is datetime which is dynamic, based on loop values.

```
SELECT [DATATIME], [prodId]
FROM
    #TEMP T 
WHERE
    prodId NOT IN (
        SELECT TOP (@PER) [prodId]
        FROM #TEMP
        WHERE
            DATATIME = @DATETIME
        GROUP BY [prodId]
        ORDER BY prodId ASC
    )
AND prodId NOT IN (
        SELECT TOP (@PER) [prodId]
        FROM #TEMP
        WHERE
            DATATIME = @DATETIME
        GROUP BY [prodId]
        ORDER BY prodId DESC
    )
AND T.DATATIME = @DATETIME
ORDER BY T.DATATIME, T.prodId
```

Now I want to do this for all datetime, how can I do this without using loop?

Comment: Meaningful, and consumable, sample data, and expected results will help us help you here.

Comment: please check the example i have given

Comment: That doesn't look particularly meaningful, and it's not consumable, nor are there expected results.

Comment: Could you show us the query you wrote? Also, it would be great if you could provide us with a  fiddle, as in http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: @MarcusViniciusPompeu I have tried it with loop and got expected result which i wanted but the loop makes the output very slow

Comment: Yep. We understood you did it within a loop :-) But, could you enrich your case with the code you wrote? And some of the data? This link https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example may help you

Comment: @MarcusViniciusPompeu please check the edit

Comment: NOW I have something to work on :-) Give me some minutes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out, please. A fiddle is here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/k4cZdjsgcV5Gc44KG3HE7m/0

```
select *
from
    (
        select
            `datetime`, ProdId,
            PERCENT_RANK()
            over(
                partition by `datetime`
                order by ProdId
            ) as percentile
        from temp
    ) d
where percentile between 0.15 and 0.85
order by `datetime`, ProdId
```

Comment: could you please explain why you took `percentile between 0.15 and 0.85` will it work as 15% of counted values of each timestamp?

Comment: Sure. The first '15%' percentile encompasses the first 15% chunk from your data. The second '15%' percentile encompasses the next chunk (from 15%+ till 30%), and so on. Hence selecting between 0.15 and 0.85 cut out those first 15% rows and those last 15%.

Comment: @PuranKandpal, in the fiddle, you may check that the '85 elements' you cited are cut as intended.

Comment: Great! Keep on. Just try next time to give some more input from start :-)